# Why cannot call scss from html in ionic4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I’m migrating source code from ionic3 to ionic4.
If I wrote the style directly in the HTML it can be applied, but I can't call scss using class in HTML.
Why I can't call scss from HTML?
It works in ionic3.

**login.page.ts**

```
..
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['login.page.scss'],
  providers: [CustomNativeStorage]
})
..
```

**login.page.html**

```
<ion-content>
..
  <div class="welcome_text">
    <h4>WELCOME_TEXT</h4>
  </div>
..
</ion-content>
```

**login.page.scss**

```
page-login {
  .welcome_text{
    margin-top: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
  }
..
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the Selector name in scss file **login.page.scss**

your code

```
page-login {
  .welcome_text{
    margin-top: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
  }
..
}
```

change to this

```
.welcome_text{
    margin-top: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think on the templateUrl and styleUrls you need a slash before, like:

```
'./login.page.html'
```

and you don't need to reference selector on the .scss file once, that is directly connect to the page.

Comment: The slash was the same with or without. But the removal of the selector worked! Thank you.